# How do I edit default message in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, filter

I would like to edit the default message in woocommerce, because they're in English and i want them in French.
For example, I would like to edit this message in the plugin booking-form:

```
$booking_form_params = array(
  ....
            'i18n_choose_options'        => __( 'Please select the options for your booking and make sure duration rules apply.', 'woocommerce-bookings' ),
```

Also, in this function there is :

```
        wp_localize_script( 'wc-bookings-booking-form', 'booking_form_params', apply_filters( 'booking_form_params', $booking_form_params ) );
```

I guess I have to use  `add_filter`, but i don't get which argument I have to use.

Comment: use wpml string translation plugin or use gettext() function.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext

Answer (score 1):

Here's is the solution if needed :

```
add_filter( 'booking_form_params', 'change_msg2',  10, 1  );
function change_msg2( $default_msg ) {
    $default_msg['i18n_choose_options' ] = 'Your new message';

    return $default_msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add following code in functions.php or any relevant file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_no_shipping_available_html', 'change_msg_no_available_shipping_methods', 10, 1  );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_no_shipping_available_html', 'change_msg_no_available_shipping_methods', 10, 1 );
function change_msg_no_available_shipping_methods( $default_msg ) {
    $custom_msg = "Call us for quotation - 1-800-XXX-XXXX";
    if( empty( $custom_msg ) ) {
      return $default_msg;
    }

    return $custom_msg;
}
```

Its just for your understanding, you may modify as per your requirements

Comment: Thanks, i just would like to know where you get the 'woocommerce_cart_no_shipping_available_html'

Comment: cart-shipping.php